# Will a variable updated in a constructor be available in a class in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In my code I have a message that is sent using an AngularJS $emit and received in a $on function in my constructor. When I debug it goes frequently to the line below so I know that's working:

```
 this.lastSuccessResponse = +new Date();
```

However when I check the console the message being printed every 60 seconds always prints `last: undefined`

Can anyone see what is wrong and why the console.log does not seem to log a new number for `lastSuccessResponse` ?

```
class ConnectService
{
    lastSuccessResponse: number;

    static $inject = [
        "$interval",
        "$rootScope"
    ];

    constructor(
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public $interval,
        public $rootScope
    ) {
        $rootScope.$on('rootScope:success-response', function () {
            this.lastSuccessResponse = +new Date();
        });
    }

    checkConnection = () => {
        var self = this;
        this.$interval(function () {
            let intDate = +new Date();
            console.log("date: " + intDate);
            console.log("last: " + self.lastSuccessResponse);
        }, 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also the entry in the TypeScript FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does-this-get-orphaned-in-my-instance-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly guarded against losing `this` in `checkConnection`, but not in the constructor

This code

```
    $rootScope.$on('rootScope:success-response', function () {
        this.lastSuccessResponse = +new Date();
    });
```

Should be this (change `function` to arrow function to preserve `this` in the callback):

```
    $rootScope.$on('rootScope:success-response', () => {
        this.lastSuccessResponse = +new Date();
    });
```